# hwmon hwmon1 : Undervoltage detected from going to current console

Tags: terminal

I have a raspberry Pi, for which I currently use the following script whilst I set some things up

```
watch -n .5 ntpq -np > /dev/tty2 &
gpsmon > /dev/tty3 &
cgps > /dev/tty4 &
watch 'ifconfig && ip route' > /dev/tty5 &
```

then use Alt-F2 etc to look at each screen
However when I am viewing , say, tty2 and an undervoltage occurs it displays a message hwmon hwmon1: undervoltage on the screen which then causes the text to be wrong due to scrolling

I want to stop or otherwise address the issue of text message causing the text alignment problems and only have the undervoltage hwmon message output on tty1 - or perhaps only on logged in ttys.

I also get the lightning bolt icon so I will be aware of the issue, which occurs when I am plugging and unplugging USB hubs - I'm hoping it is a voltage mismatch between the powered USB hub and the Raspberry PI itself as the (common) power supply is a 20A 5V and I have used dedicated large cables to the powered hub.  Its short term and does not appear to be having any other effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak from personal experience but perhaps try

[how do i disable messages or logging from printing on the console virtual termin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97256/how-do-i-disable-messages-or-logging-from-printing-on-the-console-virtual-termin/97318#97318).

> You can use the command
>
> sudo dmesg -n 1
>
> to suppress all messages from the kernel (and its
> drivers) except panic messages from appearing on the console.
>
> To fix at each boot, add the command to:
>
> /etc/rc.local

A comment from [ross](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/60277/ross)

> dmesg -n 1 does stop messages to the console but I found the message
> is still being sent to tty10 (which appears to be just the syslog) so
> this is what I needed

Comment: Thanks- I knew I had seen that command somewhere but my searches did not find it - still I want to see the messages somewhere so for the moment I re-wrote my script so that it kills and restarts all the processes eg 
bash /var/tmp/wgps1.pid
watch -n .5 ntpq -np > /dev/tty2 & echo kill $! >> /var/tmp/wgps1.pid
etc

Comment: dmesg -n 1 does stop messages to the console  but I found the message is still being sent to tty10 (which appears to be just the syslog) so this is what I needed

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I will update the answer with that information.